# CakePHP empty key for Security::cipher()

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP version 2.2.3. I want to get my cookie in an array format like-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => test1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [username] => test2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [username] => test3
        )

)
```

Below code i am getting error message. Please check my code.

```
public function broadcast($username=null) { //test1 or test2 or test3
        $this->layout = '';
        $recent = $this->Cookie->read('recentUser');
        $amount = count($recent);
        $cookieVal = array('username'=>$username);
        $this->Cookie->write('recentUser.' . $amount, $cookieVal);
        $test = $this->Cookie->read('recentUser'); 
        pr($test);
        exit;
    }
```

OutPut:

```
Warning (512): You cannot use an empty key for Security::cipher() [CORE\Cake\Utility\Security.php, line 186]

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => test3
        )

)
```

Always i am getting the last cookie which i was visiting last time with `Secrity::chiper()` error. Pleas help me how to show multiple cookie in above format?

Comment: Either you are not using 2.2.3, or the line number is wrong, line `186` would be `return $out`. And what does your `Security.salt` configuration value look like?

Comment: @ndm `Secuity.salt` problem solved. cookie `write` should be taken 4 paremeter `name`, `value`, 'false`, `expire time` above code is working but my cookies is overwrite. How to set array cookies value in a single variable?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this to see if this solves your problem

```
public function broadcast($username=null) { //test1 or test2 or test3
    $this->layout = '';
    $recent = $this->Cookie->read('recentUser');
    $amount = count($recent);
    $amount++; //Custom
    $cookieVal = array('username'=>$username);
    $this->Cookie->write('recentUser.' . $amount, $cookieVal);
    $test = $this->Cookie->read('recentUser'); 
    pr($test);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Please do not just post code, explain what your changes do and how they solve the problem. If you can't explain it, then don't post it as an answer, but use comments instead.

Comment: When he reads the amount he propably always reads 0 and overwrites the index at the cookie. So I added the ammount++ to increase to the next index.

Comment: Hello @MponosGeorge your answer is coming same error. also i am getting last cookies. Cookies over-write. Please check your code.